# Add compiling option to tex engine

Tags: latex, tex

I want to use minted package in my tex file. It needs the command-line option `--shell-escape` to allow external pygmentize program execution. How can I add that option to the tex engine?

My related code snippets are

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
          (setq TeX-auto-untabify t     ; remove all tabs before saving
                TeX-engine 'xetex       ; use xelatex default
                TeX-show-compilation t) ; display compilation windows
          (TeX-global-PDF-mode t)       ; PDF mode enable, not plain
          (setq TeX-save-query nil)
          (imenu-add-menubar-index)
          (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'TeX-complete-symbol)))
```

I tried to add `(add-to-list 'tex-compile-commands '("xelatex --shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f" t "%r.pdf"))`, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to the list of local variables of the source file:

```
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
```

Then you need to do `M-x revert-buffer` to make it applied.

[AUCTeX 12.2: 4.1.3 Options for TeX Processors](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Processor-Options.html)

[How to pass flags to the LaTeX compiler with AUCTeX? - Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33209/how-to-pass-flags-to-the-latex-compiler-with-auctex)

[emacs - Adding an option to the PDFLaTeX call from AUCTeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157242/adding-an-option-to-the-pdflatex-call-from-auctex)

Comment: Are you assuming that one needs AUCTeX for your solution?  What if I'm using plain vanilla`tex-mode`? I tried your solution, it didn't work.

Comment: @OskarLimka I don't think AUCTeX is a must, since I use `describe-variable` to find `TeX-command-extra-options` is defined in `tex.el`. It has been a long time since last time I used latex in emacs, I almost forgot how things go. I think you can try to find if the value of `TeX-command-extra-options` was passed to tex engine first.

Comment: thank you. This is how the first line of my master latex file looks like `%%% -*- mode: latex; reftex-mode: true; coding: mule-utf-8;  TeX-command-extra-options: "-synctex=1"; -*-` but when I xelatex compile by running 'C-c C-c` emacs issues `xelatex \\nonstopmode\\input lecture.tex` in the `*tex-shell*` buffer.

Comment: @OskarLimka I don't know what does `;` mean in your first line, the format looks werid to me. I use it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TDfc.png).